# Will TFRecordWriter replace existed tfrecords?

Tags: python, tensorflow

Let's say I've already have a tfrecords named `a.tfrecords`.

Now I generate another tfrecords file also named `a.tfrecords` with 
`tfrecordWriter = tf.python_io.TFRecordWriter('a.tfrecords')`.

I'm wondering if the old tfrecords file be replaced(removed) or continue adding data into the old tfrecords file?

Comment: Why don't you try and see?

Comment: @Guy Well, I tried just now. The answer is the old one will be replaced.

Answer (score 0):

I tried by myself. The answer is the old tfrecords file will be replaced by the new one.